# Oxford comma in subject

Tags: oxford-comma

I know that there are different opinions regarding Oxford comma, but I am taking IELTS soon, and I want to know if I should use it when my list is the subject of a sentence.

Example:
Spain, Austria, Germany and Spain use recycling as the main form of waste management.

Personally, I would not put a comma before "and Spain", but I wonder whether it would be grammatically correct to put it there.

Comment: Probably acceptable either way. What is not acceptable is to be inconsistent. Pick a way and use it all the time.

Comment: For an illustration of why the Oxford comma is often recommended, read about [this court case](https://qz.com/1204146/oxford-comma-court-case-maines-oakhurst-dairy-has-settled-with-its-drivers-for-5-million/), where a company was found to owe drivers overtime because a law omitted an Oxford comma. It's the difference between "The canning, processing, preserving,
freezing, drying, marketing, storing,
**packing for shipment or distribution** of" and "The canning, processing, preserving,
freezing, drying, marketing, storing,
**packing for shipment**, or **distribution** of."

Comment: If you can tell an Oxford comma from any other kind, then the simplest rule is: Always use the Oxford comma. However, if you can't tell whether a comma has been to Oxford or not, don't worry about it. Just put'em where you hear'em.

Comment: In this case, you can leave off the seconds Spain. ;-)

Comment: @jimm101  :D it's a typo, one of the Spains was supposed to be Sweden!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In [this article](https://ted-ielts.com/oxford-comma-ielts/), from July 2019, the author, an IELTS tutor, **highly recommends** using the Oxford comma for clarity and to prevent confusion, although it is **not mandatory**.

To exemplify the problem:

> Spain, Austria, Germany and Spain

Here, the last item is 'Germany and Spain' - strictly speaking there are not four different countries, but two single countries, and one combination of two.

By adding the Oxford comma,

> Spain, Austria, Germany, and Spain

the summation becomes one of four different, single countries. This is probably the meaning you want to convey (but it might not be!).

Or, to illustrate it humorously, and to borrow from the linked article again:

[image: Oxford comma joke]

Comment: Can the down-voter please expand on their action? I wouldn't mind being able to improve my answer.